# drag using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, drag

I want to create a web page in which a specific image is capable to drag.

so this was my code.

```
<! doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
   <script src="13.8.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="file:\\C:\Users\X555\Pictures\poster\yellowflowers.png" id="image" alt="white lion">

    <script>
        var mustDrag;
        var image


        function set() {
            image = document.getElementById("image");
            image.addEventListener("mousedown", function () { mustDrag = true }, false);
            window.addEventListener("mouseup", function () { mustDrag = false; }, false);


            window.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);
        }

        function drag(e) {

            if (mustDrag) {
                e.target.style.position = 'absolute';
                e.target.style.left = Number(e.x);
                e.target.style.top = Number(e.y);
            }

        }
        window.addEventListener("load", set, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't function correctly .sometimes it drag whit it shouldn't. and usually throw the image in lower-left side of the window while it mustn't. I don't realize at all that whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3):

> Refer this Example, hope you will get your answer

```js
 function startDrag(e) {
    // determine event object
    if (!e) {
     var e = window.event;
    }
                if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    // IE uses srcElement, others use target
    targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    if (targ.className != 'dragme') {return};
    // calculate event X, Y coordinates
     offsetX = e.clientX;
     offsetY = e.clientY;

    // assign default values for top and left properties
    if(!targ.style.left) { targ.style.left='0px'};
    if (!targ.style.top) { targ.style.top='0px'};

    // calculate integer values for top and left 
    // properties
    coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
    coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
    drag = true;

    // move div element
     document.onmousemove=dragDiv;
                return false;
    
   }
   function dragDiv(e) {
    if (!drag) {return};
    if (!e) { var e= window.event};
    // var targ=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;
    // move div element
    targ.style.left=coordX+e.clientX-offsetX+'px';
    targ.style.top=coordY+e.clientY-offsetY+'px';
    return false;
   }
   function stopDrag() {
    drag=false;
   }
   window.onload = function() {
    document.onmousedown = startDrag;
    document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
   }
```

```css
 .dragme{
   position:relative;
   width: 270px;
   height: 203px;
   cursor: move;
  }
 #draggable {
   background-color: #ccc;
   border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
   
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-8tqTFxi2ebU/Ufo4j_thf7I/AAAAAAAADFM/_ZBQctm9e8E/w270-h203-no/flower.jpg" alt="drag-and-drop image script" 
 title="drag-and-drop image script" class="dragme">

 <div id="draggable" class="dragme">Test </div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate Shrinath, I'm searching this type of code  from a long time, a lot of thanks for it.

Comment: thank Shrinath but there are two problems yet.
1-I don't know jQuery yet so I don't know what offsetX  is .
2-then my dominant problem is with "what's wrong in my code".It seems for me every thing is correct but it isn't .where is the mistake of code?

Comment: I think I find it .I must subtract canvas.offsetLeft from the clientx