# What is the easiest way to drag an element in an arc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code for my "program". The jQuery to drag the sun is at the very bottom. The sun is an image. What is the easiest way to drag the sun in an arc?

```
    <style>
        /* Colors */
        body {
             /*clouds*/
             background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png);
             animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -moz-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
        }
        /*cloud animation*/
        @keyframes mymove {
            0% { background-position: 0 0; }
            50% { background-position: 40% 0; }
        }
        #sun {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 30%;
            left: 10%;
        }
    </style>

    <html>
    <body>
            <img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">
    </body>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*sun dragged in a line*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#sun").draggable({axis: "x"});
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: please refer [Drag using Javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818714/drag-using-javascript-and-css/32818844#32818844

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got a pretty nice arcing motion going on here, it's based on a circle formula. You can change the arc by changing the variables in the formula. Tell me what you think.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$("#sun").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    drag: function() {
        var xpos = parseFloat(this.style.left, 10) - 200;
        var ypos = Math.sqrt(300 * 300 - xpos * xpos) * 0.75;
        this.style["margin-top"] = (-ypos) + "px";
    }
});
```

```css
/* Colors */
 body {
    /*clouds*/
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png);
    animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*cloud animation*/
 @keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 40% 0;
    }
}
#sun {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 30%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<img id="sun" src="https://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/on1z6q0z/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking everywhere for a solution.